# How to get the Foreign Key set on the URL and use it on django CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

Thanks for your time...

If someone can help me to get the foreign key that shows on the URL and use it on Django CreateView.

I am trying to create a simple app to organize legislation.  For this, I have this relation on my database: Categoria has many Series and Series has many posts.

I have made the one path of **urls.py** like this

```
(...)
path('nova-serie/<categoria>', NovaSerie.as_view(), name='nova_serie'), 
(...)
```

I just want to pass **get the value from the URL and save as the foreign key** without the user have to type it again.

[image: I want to get the foreign key and save it without the user has to type it again]

**view.py**

```py
class NovaCategoria(CreateView):
    model = Categoria
    form_class = CategoriaForm
    template_name = 'nova_categoria.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

class NovaSerie(CreateView):
    model = Serie
    form_class = SerieForm
    template_name = 'nova_serie.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

**models.py**

```py
class Categoria(models.Model):
    categoria = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, verbose_name="Nome da categoria", help_text="colocar aqui o texto de ajuda")
   
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categorias"
        verbose_name = "categoria"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoria

class Serie(models.Model):
    serie = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, verbose_name="Série", help_text="colocar aqui o texto de ajuda")
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "serie"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.serie
```

**forms.py**

```py
class SerieForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Serie
        fields = (
            'serie',
            'categoria',
        )
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(),  # attrs={class="title"}
            'categoria': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "green", 'value': object }),  # attrs={class="title"}
        }

class CategoriaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Categoria
        fields = (
            'categoria',
        )
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(),  # attrs={class="title"}
        }
```

If you have found any issues with this post, please let me know.  I will be glad to change it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this happen we need to make basically two things:

1. on `url.py` we need to tell Django that it´s an integer
2. on views.py use the `form_valid`

#### url.py

so your urls.py should have something like that:

```py
path('nova-serie/<int:categoria>', NovaSerie.as_view(), name='nova_serie'),
```

#### views.py

```
class NovaSerie(CreateView):
    model = Serie
    form_class = SerieForm
    template_name = 'nova_serie.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.categoria_id = self.kwargs['categoria']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

With those changes, I was able to make it happens!

I am a newbie, if I should edit or delete this post, please let me know

The solution was given by mr. **@Willem Van Onsem**